# To show multimedia content(e.g audio,video,jpeg) from custom folder to a Dialog as file explorer.

Tags: android, video, explorer, multimedia

I am creating an android app, in which i have created a custom location in external storage ,for example /storage/emulated/0/myfolder/. And it contains my app files which are video,audio and pictures(.mp4,.3gpp,.jpeg).
Is there any way to show the contents of myfolder to a popup or some dialog in list manner.Which will behave like explorer and upon clicking any item in the list ,it will run in appropriate application(e.g video player,audio player or picture viewer).Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
File dir = new File(
     Environment
       .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(File.separator),
     "custom folder name");
   String[] files = null;
   if (dir.exists()) {
    files = dir.list();
}
```

Now with this files array i extraceted each element and checked its extension to get the mime type and showed accordingly.It worked for me.Most simple code for what i want to achieve.